# Mongo Aggregation group data into single document

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm having the following output from an aggregation group stage

```
[
 {
   "region": "region1",
   "business": "Electronics",
   "country": "US"
 },
 {
   "region": "region1",
   "business": "Medical",
   "country": "US"
 },
 {
   "region": "region1",
   "business": "Electronics",
   "country": "UK"
 },
 {
   "region": "region2",
   "business": "Automotive",
   "country": "Japan"
 },
 {
   "region": "region2",
   "business": "Food",
   "country": "China"
 }
]
```

And I want to consolidate the output as the following:

```
[
 {
   "region": "region1",
   "business": [
      { "Electronics": ["UK", "US"] },
      { "Medical": ["US"] }
   ]
 },
 {
   "region": "region2",
   "business": [
      { "Automotive": ["Japan"] },
      { "Food": ["China"] }
   ]
 }
]
```

Which aggregation can I use here to do this consolidation dynamically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Group by `region` and `business` and push `country` into the `countries` array.
2. Group by `region` and push key-value pair (k: `business`, v: `countries`) into the `business` array.
3. Set the `business` field to convert each key-value pair into an object and match the desired output.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        region: "$region",
        business: "$business"
      },
      countries: {
        $push: "$country"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id.region",
      business: {
        $push: {
          k: "$_id.business",
          v: "$countries"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      business: {
        $map: {
          input: "$business",
          in: {
            $arrayToObject: [
              [
                "$$this"
              ]
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KqC0yjcMvCc)